# AndroidManifest error in android or in flutter app also

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest, aapt, aapt2

Whenever i run the flutter run -v i get error in aapt dump xmltree. so now i separately run the aapt dump command so i get the erro in AndroidManifest.xml which is not able to open.

**Coomand**

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3>aapt dump  C:\Users\admin\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

**Output**

```
Binary APK
Package name=com.example.flutter_app id=7f
  type drawable id=01 entryCount=1
    resource 0x7f010000 drawable/launch_background
      () (file) res/drawable/launch_background.xml type=XML
  type mipmap id=02 entryCount=1
    resource 0x7f020000 mipmap/ic_launcher
      (mdpi) (file) res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png type=PNG
      (hdpi) (file) res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png type=PNG
      (xhdpi) (file) res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png type=PNG
      (xxhdpi) (file) res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png type=PNG
      (xxxhdpi) (file) res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png type=PNG
  type style id=03 entryCount=1
    resource 0x7f030000 style/LaunchTheme
      () (style) size=1 parent=0x01030009
        0x01010054=@drawable/launch_background


W/ziparchive( 5152): Unable to open 'AndroidManifest.xml': No such file or directory
AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to open file: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
```

Comment: can you open AndroidManifest.xml manually?

Comment: got solution..?